# 64-bit Windows CE 5.0 Emulator

Tags: 64-bit, windows-ce, emulation

When attempting to run the Windows CE 5.0 emulator on my 64-bit system, I get the following error:

> "Emulator for Windows CE is incompatible with the host operating system.
>
> Emulator for CE will not run on 64-bit host operating systems.64-bit host operating systems."

How can I run the Windows CE 5.0 Emulator under 64-bit Windows 7 without resorting to a VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  The old CE 5.0 emulator is an x86 emulator and must run on a 32-bit target.  If you need to run on a 64-bit machine, use [Device Emulator 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114&displaylang=en) (which is what Studio 2008 is using).  Of course that also means you have the generate an OS image for it using [the proper BSP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=474B03A6-E87D-455D-BC16-B8CF18EF39B4&displaylang=en).