# window CE with vs 2010

Tags: c#, window, windows-ce

I am new to window CE, and i need to do a window CE program. my pc has VS 2010 installed.
im wondering does visual studio 2010 support window CE program?
why my computer cannot install  window CE emulator?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot create windows CE programs with Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio 2008 does support this and Microsoft apparently plans to support .NET CF (which is the .NET platform Windows CE uses) in VS 2012.

See for instance this post with over 600 upvotes: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are installing the correct bit? 64bit/32bit?

I'm developing a Windows CE app at the moment and can definitely tell you that VS2010 does not support it. VS2005 and 2008 is your best options.

It would probably be best to Google the error you get when your installation fails.

Comment: i download the emulator from < http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18481 >. it doesn't tell whether it is 64bits or 32bits, my pc is 64bits.

Comment: @user1914546 Please check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005597/64-bit-windows-ce-5-0-emulator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004853/windows-ce-5-0-emulator-needed. Please validate

Comment: ok. i got the idea. 
As im new to window CE. could you please tell me more on software needed to develop a window CE program using vs2008. other than the emulator. Thx in advance :D
@Werner van den Heever

Comment: When you finally got Windows CE to work. Install Virtual Pc2007 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4580 . When you debug your app the Emulator needs a virtual network card which Virtual Pc2007 installs for you. Other than that you don't really use it. Also, Windows Mobile Device Center http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3182 . ActiveSync won't work if you have Vista/Win7/Win8.
Goodluck